# Writing $\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}$ in terms of partial fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

How does one write

$$\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}$$

in terms of partial fractions?

**My Attempt**

$$\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}=\frac{x^4-4x^5+6x^6-4x^7+x^8}{1+x^2}$$

$$=Ax^6+Bx^5+Cx^4+Dx^3+Ex^2+Fx+\frac{G}{1+x^2}$$

Multiplying out and comparing coefficient gives:

$$=x^6-4x^5+5x^4-4x^2+0+\frac{0}{1+x^2}$$

This is obviously not correct, how to do this properly?

Comment: @Alizter Every real polynomial of degree $>1$ **can** be factored: in $\Bbb C$. While it's probably not what is meant by the OP, your statement is wrong (you can do partial fraction decomposition in $\Bbb C$ too).

Comment: Notice you should have a fraction $\displaystyle{\frac{G+Hx}{1+x^2}}$ left. However, the result has $H=0$. Indeed,
$$\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}=x^6-4x^5-4x^2+4-\frac{4}{1+x^2}$$
The easiest to find this (not necessarily the shortest) is [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division). There is also what is called in french "division suivant les puissances croissantes", I don't know the english equivalent.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks. Im curious, how could find this using polynomial long division

Comment: I'd do it by long division.  First expand $x^4(1-x)^4$ to $x^4-4x^5+6x^6-4x^7+x^8$, then divide. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy (thumbs up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have tried
$$\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}=Ax^6+Bx^5+Cx^4+Dx^3+Ex^2+Fx +\mathbf{J}+\frac{\mathbf{G + Hx}}{1+x^2}$$

By the way, multiplying out and comparing coefficients gives:
$$\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}=x^6-4x^5+5x^4-4x^2+\mathbf{4}+\frac{\mathbf{-4}}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Thnx uuuuuuuuuuuu

Answer (score 3):

To answer your comment about long division: you want to divide $x^8-4x^7+6x^6-4x^5+x^4$ by $x^2+1$. Then,

$$x^8-4x^7+6x^6=x^6(x^2+1)-4x^7+5x^6$$
$$-4x^7+5x^6-4x^5=-4x^5(x^2+1)+5x^6$$
$$5x^6+x^4=5x^4(x^2+1)-4x^4$$
$$-4x^4=-4x^2(x^2+1)+4x^2$$
$$4x^2=4(x^2+1)-4$$

All in all,

$$x^8-4x^7+6x^6-4x^5+x^4=(x^6-4x^5+5x^4-4x^2+4)(x^2+1)-4$$

Or

$$\frac{x^8-4x^7+6x^6-4x^5+x^4}{x^2+1}=x^6-4x^5+5x^4-4x^2+4-\frac4{x^2+1}$$

Usually you write it like this

First step:

```
x^8 -4x^7 +6x^6 -4x^5 +x^4    | x^2 + 0x + 1
    -4x^7 +5x^6 -4x^5 +x^4    +-----------------------
                              | x^6
```

Second step:

```
x^8 -4x^7 +6x^6 -4x^5 +x^4    | x^2 + 0x + 1
    -4x^7 +5x^6 -4x^5 +x^4    +-----------------------
          +5x^6 +0x^5 +x^4    | x^6 -4x^5
```

Then, the complete division:

```
x^8 -4x^7 +6x^6 -4x^5 +x^4            | x^2 + 0x + 1
    -4x^7 +5x^6 -4x^5 +x^4            +-----------------------
          +5x^6 +0x^5 +x^4            | x^6 -4x^5 +5x^4 -4x^2 +4
                     -4x^4            |
                            4x^2      |
                                 -4   |
```

It's not very easy to write or to read on computer, so feel free to ask if something is not clear enough.

Comment: (upvoted!) Cheers...Thnx you so much. I understood and eveything is clear.